# do stuff to any data which comes from ajax requests

Tags: jquery

is it possible to catch anything that comes from the server via ajax ?
I know that the ajaxComplete() fires when some ajax work completes

I would like to e.g.

```
alert(whichever content came from the server as a result for $.ajax, $.post, $.get)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Even the jQuery manual shows examples that do exactly what you want.

Comment: @Omu you are not serious, are you? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, the description of the `success` callback

Comment: @Pekka no I don't want to do this on success, more like a global function, for any ajax response

Comment: @Omu ah, that makes more sense. I would clarify the question accordingly... I don't think there is a global function for that, though

Comment: You will then have to write your own generic method to get the ajax response where you do this logic onsuccess or onfailure. Then you can reuse this method for all your ajaxcalls.

Comment: @Omu: What's wrong with using ajaxComplete? It does what you're asking for, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery.ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) should do just fine.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, XHR, ajaxOptions) {
    var resp = XHR.responseText 
                ? XHR.responseText 
                : (XHR.responseHTML
                    ? XHR.responseHTML
                    : XHR.responseXML);
    alert(resp);
});
```

The documentation says that the response will be in `XHR.responseHTML` or `XHR.responseXML`, but I suspect the latter might be a typo, since my empirical test show that the two members present are `XHR.responseText` and `XHR.responseHTML`.

But then again, my tests weren't exhaustive and didn't take in account the mime type returned by the server, so don't take my word for it, as I might be horribly mistaken.

Also this example blatantly ignores the status code returned and should by no means be taken as a good example, merely as a possible starting point.

See an [ugly running demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeucs/2/)